# SharePoint Document or Item Download/View Event Handler?

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling

Is there any way to capture document download or item view actions in SharePoint 2010/2007?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar requirement in that I had to send an email when a document was downloaded. In WSS 3.0, I wrote an Http Module that looked at the request url and if the prefix of the request matched my document library URL, I captured that download/view.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site collection audit settings. Under Documents and Items, check Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Views of Items (not documents) are not audited. We have created a separate feature for auditing those.